# JSON to TABLE in PHP

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

for anyone who can give a hand. Thanks a lot.

I can't get the JSON data to get into the table. I don't know if it's a problem with the data request path...
When I do // var_dump ($ results); I check that the results of the api (url) are loaded in the page but I don't know what error I made when trying to introduce them in the table

```
 add_shortcode( 'external_data', 'callback_function_name');
    
    function callback_function_name() {
    
    
       $url = 'https:
    
        
            $arguments = array(
            'method' => 'GET',
        );
    
        $response = wp_remote_get( $url, $arguments );
    
        $results = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
    
        // var_dump($results);
    
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<table>';
    
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>name</td>';
        $html .= '<td>suite</td>';
        $html .= '<td>display_name</td>';
        $html .= '<td>id</td>';
        $html .= '<td>conference</td>';
        $html .= '<td>division</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        
        foreach( $results as $result ) {
            
            
            $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->name . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->nickname . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->display_name . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->id . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->conference . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->division . '</td>';
            $html .= '</tr>';
            
    
            }
            
            $html .= '</table>';
            
            return $html;
            
        }
```

Comment: Check structure of JSON. It must be `foreach ($results->results->data->team as $result`. Also don't post API token publicly.

Comment: … but instead include proper information of what the JSON actually looks like then, because without the API key we would not have known that in this instance here in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lots for your comments. Do you know how could I add filters or sort the table results?

Answer (score 0):

fgYou can use file_get_contents

```
function callback_function_name() {
  $data=file_get_contents('https://https://delivery.oddsandstats.co/team_list/NFL.JSON?api_key=your api key');

   $data=(array)json_decode($data);
   $result=(array)$data['results'];
   $teams=$result['data']->team;
 
     $html = '';
        $html .= '<table>';
    
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>name</td>';
        $html .= '<td>suite</td>';
        $html .= '<td>display_name</td>';
        $html .= '<td>id</td>';
        $html .= '<td>conference</td>';
        $html .= '<td>division</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        
        foreach( $teams as $result ) {
            
            
            $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->name . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->nickname . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->display_name . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->id . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->conference . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $result->division . '</td>';
            $html .= '</tr>';
            
    
            }
            
            $html .= '</table>';
            
            return $html;
          }
```

Comment: Great!! Sure you know very well what it feels like when you have been trying for hours to figure out what is wrong and you finally see it working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Subbu, do you know how could I add filters or sort the table results?

Comment: use datatables plugin to add search filter and sort fields

Comment: while this is working, there are rooms for improvements. Validation & null checking are required and the URL of the `file_get_contents()` is incorrect; unnecessary to cast the variable as array (you should check whether it's an array instead).